# Electric field from charge density

Tags: electromagnetism

This Maxwell law tells us that the rate of change of the electric field created by a charge density:

[image]

depends on the charge density  and the permittivity of the material outside the charge density. Is this valid only for 3D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is a finite small volume hence 3D, but a [2D slice can be computed](http://www.falstad.com/vector3dm/vector3dm.html?f=SolenoidField&d=viewpaper&sl=x&st=20&vd=16&a1=40&a2=30&a3=36&rx=73&ry=0&rz=0&zm=1.2)
Rotate the object and change the views.